# How to display the 'Project Resource' and 'Experimental Releases' project portlets in Plone Software Center?

Tags: plone

I have installed Plone Software Center 1.6.4 in a Plone 4.2.4 instance. In the software projects I instantiate the project logo appears in the right side-bar, but neither the 'Project Resources' nor the 'Experimental Releases' portlets appear. They are evidently visible in the PSC at plone.org. Any suggestions how I can display these portlets would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The portlets included in Plone Software Center are 'classic portlets'; they predate the current portlet system and are purely skin templates, really.

To include these, add a 'Classic portlet' to the Software Project type (in the site setup -> Types -> select 'Software Project' in the dropdown box -> Manage portlets assigned to this content type).

The Classic Portlet type takes two parameters, a template and a macro. The PSC portlets you are looking for use the `portlet_project_resources` and `portlet_project_roadmap` templates, in both the macro is called `portlet`.

Comment: @mge: Could Martjin's answer help you further or do you need more details?